# How to correctly dock/undock a laptop under Ubuntu?

Tags: lenovo, dock

I'm with lenovo x1 yoga and lenovo onelink dock.
There is just one button on the dock for power on/off

Is there something i should do before pulling out the dock cable from the laptop to gracefully undock? Or just pull it like a barbarian and call it a day?

Comment: What does the machine's instruction manual recommend?

Comment: Not a word about that

Answer (score 1):

It is safe for your laptop to pull the cable.

Laptops usually have an UPS (uninterruptible power supply) integrated. The UPS switches to the Battery immediately when pulling a power cable.

That said, you must take care of USB Storage devices connected to the dock like external HDDs and USB Sticks. To prevent data loss unmount them before pulling the cable.

Comment: Is there anything I need to do, so the windows are in tact when I return to the dock?
External monitor and laptop are different resolution.s